# Entity Framework context format

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm just now learning MVC4 and Entity Framework.  Some examples I have seen have all the "DbSet"s in one class, other I have seen each model have the DbSet in it.  Is there an advantage of one way or the other?   I kinda like having ONE "MyDbContext" model that references all the other models, but not sure which is better.  Any thoughts and real life issues with either way?

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

public class UsersPostsContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<UserPost> UserPosts { get; set; }
}
```

Verses:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserPost> UserPosts { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Could you show that both examples you described?

Comment: Added example to original post, comments wouldn't let me format the code for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is *definitely* not the way to go.

It defeats the power of EF to handle complex object graphs. What if you want to retrieve users *and* their posts *and* profiles from the database? (Just a random example). You'd need three contexts and a lot of cunning to put the right objects together. And that's only the reading part. CUD actions are even more complex, if only the logic you need to do inserts/deletes in the right order and set FK associations.

That does not necessarily mean that, consequently, you should always have one context class. It can be beneficial to have several of them for parts of the database that logically belong together and are relatively isolated from other parts (like authorization tables, CRM tables, product tables, reporting, ...). In this case you may decide to use [bounded contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I use the second notation because that context is more flexible to use. You don't have to wonder which object to pass to the service for example. You don't have to manage a numer of files so it is easier to understand database schema.

Comment: I like the 2nd too because all the DbSets are in one class but I've seen people do it the other way too and just wanted to find the way that makes life easier for me.  Thanks for your input.