# Don't understand DbContext -- per application or per model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the idea behind a `DbContext` class (EF)? Should I have one per model, one per application or maybe something else?

I guess I don't understand what they're used for. I get that I can put my data fetching logic in there, and that's great, but in that case, it seems to me that I should have one per model. Although if I have one per model, VS will create one connection string for each `DbContext`, ie. for each model. I'm surely missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the "connection to the database" so to speak, and you would generally have one for each database you connect to. In general this is one per application. See, having a list of models is great, but you have to yet still have a connection to the actual database to get the data *into those models.*

Answer (score 4):

The thing to keep in mind about DbContext is that it keeps track of changes to data and performs all updates/inserts/deletes when you call SaveChanges. So if you have multiple concurrent users you definitely need multiple instances of DbContext class.

Think of DbContext as a scope of certain actions that users will perform in our application. For web applications we would normally create a new DbContext for every web request. When a user list blog entries, adds a comment or edits a post we always create a new DbContext, read data into it, modify the data when necessary and then call SaveChanges. At that point EF figures out what needs to be updated in the DB and issues appropriate queries to the database.

Because of the way SaveChanges works you can think of DbContext lifecycle almost as of database transaction. DbContext wraps all things that must happen to process a request successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question not too long ago.  From what I understand it's better to have all DbContext's in ONE class.  Here is link to my post:

[Entity Framework context format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437780/entity-framework-context-format/20447995?noredirect=1#20447995)